# log4net, separate processes, separate RollingFileAppenders

Tags: c#, log4net

We have a Windows Service that kicks off another process called ClusterProcess.
I want to get logs from the Windows Service and from the ClusterProcess, and I want those logs to go to the database and to files. For instance, if the database is not accessible, I want to be able to see the logs in the files.

I have an external config file for the Log4Net settings. There are two RollingFileAppenders and two AdoNetAppenders.
There is the default root logger and an additional logger called, ClusterProcessLogger.

The idea is that the Windows Service uses the root logger and logs to one of the AdoNetAppenders and one of the RollingFileAppenders, and that the ClusterProcess uses the ClusterProcessLogger and logs to the other AdoNetAppender and the other RollingFileAppender.

The AdoNetAppenders for both cases work fine. The RollingFileAppenders do not.

So here is the external config file for the log4net configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net debug="true">

<appender name="RollingFileAppender" 
type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
<file value="C:\Program Files\Sym\Logging\CalcEngineLog.txt"/>
<appendToFile value="true"/>
<rollingStyle value="Size"/>
<maxSizeRollBackups value="5"/>
<maximumFileSize value="10MB"/>
<staticLogFileName value="true"/>
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
  <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger %location - 
%message%newline%exception"/>
</layout>
<filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
  <levelMin value="DEBUG"/>
  <levelMax value="FATAL"/>
</filter>
<filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" />
</appender>

<appender name="SpecialRollingFileAppender" 
type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
<file value="C:\Program Files\Sym\Logging\SpecialCalcEngineLog.txt"/>
<appendToFile value="true"/>
<rollingStyle value="Size"/>
<maxSizeRollBackups value="5"/>
<maximumFileSize value="10MB"/>
<staticLogFileName value="true"/>
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
  <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger %location - 
%message%newline%exception"/>
</layout>
<filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
  <levelMin value="DEBUG"/>
  <levelMax value="FATAL"/>
</filter>
<filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" />
</appender>

<appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
<!--<threshold value="Error" />-->
<bufferSize value="1" />
<connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, 
Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
<connectionString value="" />
<commandText value="INSERT INTO [Calculation Engine Log] ([Date],[Thread], 
[Level],[Logger],[Location],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@log_date, 
@thread, @log_level, @logger, @location, @message, @exception)" />
<parameter>
  <parameterName value="@log_date" />
  <dbType value="DateTime" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
</parameter>
<parameter>
  <parameterName value="@thread" />
  <dbType value="String" />
  <size value="255" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
  </layout>
</parameter>
<parameter>
  <parameterName value="@log_level" />
  <dbType value="String" />
  <size value="50" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%level" />
  </layout>
</parameter>
<parameter>
  <parameterName value="@logger" />
  <dbType value="String" />
  <size value="255" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
  </layout>
</parameter>
<parameter>
  <parameterName value="@location" />
  <dbType value="String" />
  <size value="255" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%location" />
  </layout>
</parameter>
<parameter>
  <parameterName value="@message" />
  <dbType value="String" />
  <size value="4000" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%message" />
  </layout>
</parameter>
<parameter>
  <parameterName value="@exception" />
  <dbType value="String" />
  <size value="2000" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
</parameter>
</appender>

<appender name="ClusterProcessAdoNetAppender" 
type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
<bufferSize value="1" />
<connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, 
Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
<connectionString value="" />
<commandText value="INSERT INTO [ClusterProcess Calculation Engine Log] 
([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@log_date, 
@thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)" />
<parameter>
  <parameterName value="@log_date" />
  <dbType value="DateTime" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
</parameter>
<parameter>
  <parameterName value="@thread" />
  <dbType value="String" />
  <size value="255" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
  </layout>
</parameter>
<parameter>
  <parameterName value="@log_level" />
  <dbType value="String" />
  <size value="50" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%level" />
  </layout>
</parameter>
<parameter>
  <parameterName value="@logger" />
  <dbType value="String" />
  <size value="255" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
  </layout>
</parameter>
<parameter>
  <parameterName value="@message" />
  <dbType value="String" />
  <size value="4000" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%message" />
  </layout>
</parameter>
<parameter>
  <parameterName value="@exception" />
  <dbType value="String" />
  <size value="2000" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
</parameter>
</appender>

<logger name="ClusterProcessLogger" additivity="false">
<level value="Debug" />
<appender-ref ref="ClusterProcessAdoNetAppender" />
<appender-ref ref="SpecialRollingFileAppender" />
</logger>

<root>
<level value="Debug"/>
<appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender"/>
<appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
</root>

</log4net>
```

Here is the Main method of the Windows Service:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.ServiceProcess;
    using System.Text;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Globalization;
    using Sym.Core.Culture;
    using System.Threading;


    namespace Sym.WindowsService
    {
        static class Program
        {

            private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

            static void Main()
            {
                if (!log4net.LogManager.GetRepository().Configured)
                {
                    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new FileInfo("C:\\Program Files\\Sym\\bin\\Log4NetSettingsGlobal.xml"));
                }

                log.Debug("Culture info before change: " + Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name);

                ...

            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the App.config of the Windows Service:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
      <appSettings>
        <add key="ConfigPath" value="C:\Program Files\Sym\Configs\Example.config"/>
        <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
      </appSettings>
      <system.diagnostics>
        <trace autoflush="true">
          <listeners>
            <add
                name="textWriterTraceListener"
                type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
                initializeData="C:\Program Files\Sym\Logging\Log4Net_Trace_WindowsServer.txt" />
          </listeners>
        </trace>
      </system.diagnostics>
    <startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>
```

For the ClusterProcess project, here is the Main method:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using Sym.Core.Config;
    using Sym.Clustering.Framework;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using Sym.Core.Services;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.IO;
    using log4net.Repository.Hierarchy;
    using log4net;
    using log4net.Appender;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Collections.Specialized;
    using Sym.Core.Log4Net;
    using log4net.Config;


    namespace Sym.Clustering.ClusterProcess
    {
        class Program
        {
            private static  ClusterProcessor _ClusterProcessor ;       
            private static SelectedConfiguration _Config;

            private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("ClusterProcessLogger");

            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                try 
                {
                    ...                         

                    try
                    {
                        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(); 
                        if (!log4net.LogManager.GetRepository().Configured)
                        {
                            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new FileInfo("C:\\Program Files\\Sym\\bin\\Log4NetSettingsGlobal.xml"));
                        }
                        Log4NetConfiguration.ConfigureLog4Net(_Config); // Load connection strings
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e);
                    }

                    log.Debug("ClusterProcess using DatabaseName: " + config.Database.DatabaseName);

                    ...
                }
                catch(Exception exp)
                {
                    log.Error(exp.Message, exp);
                }

            }       
        }
    }
```

Here is the App.config of the ClusterProcess project:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
      <appSettings>
        <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
      </appSettings>
      <system.diagnostics>
        <trace autoflush="true">
          <listeners>
            <add
                name="textWriterTraceListener"
                type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
                initializeData="C:\Program Files\Sym\Logging\Log4Net_Trace_ClusterProcess.txt" />
          </listeners>
        </trace>
      </system.diagnostics>


    </configuration>
```

In the log4net trace of the ClusterProcess, these errors are given:

> log4net:ERROR Failed to find configuration section 'log4net' in the application's .config file. Check your .config file for the `<log4net>` and `<configSections>` elements. The configuration section should look like:

```
<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
```

> log4net:ERROR [RollingFileAppender] ErrorCode: GenericFailure. Unable to acquire lock on file C:\Program Files\Sym\Logging\SpecialCalcEngineLog.txt. The process cannot access the file 'C:\Program Files\Sym\Logging\SpecialCalcEngineLog.txt' because it is being used by another process.
>
> log4net:ERROR [RollingFileAppender] ErrorCode: GenericFailure. Unable to acquire lock on file C:\Program Files\Sym\Logging\CalcEngineLog.txt. The process cannot access the file 'C:\Program Files\Sym\Logging\CalcEngineLog.txt' because it is being used by another process.

I don't know what to do about the first error.
The second and third error shouldn't be there. The ClusterProcess should be able to access the SpecialCalcEngineLog.txt, and it shouldn't be bothered with the CalcEngineLog.txt, as that is the RollingFileAppender that the Windows Service is using.

How do I solve these errors? What am I overlooking?

Comment: Not sure whether it is possible to do this using one configuration file. As I understand the appenders are all initialised when logging first starts and so both processes will attempt to open all files.

Comment: Obviously, I do not know either. :-) But what would the point be of using different loggers then?

Comment: There are many reasons for having multiple loggers in the same application, for example you might want log to different files depending on the what part of your program is creating the log entry, or you many want normal log messages written to disk, but errors to be emailed etc.  But in your case, it would easier to use two separate configuration files.

Comment: Sigh... but I so wanted it all in one file.

Comment: If you really want one file and your logging load is low or you don't mind the performance hit, you could add `<lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />` to your appenders..

Answer (score 0):

First error can be mitigated by adding

```
<configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="System.Configuration.IgnoreSectionHandler" />
</configSections>
```

somewhere.

Multiple RollingFileAppenders cannot write to the same file. However, you can distinguish by, for example, adding process id to the file name (and then collect logs from all processes):

```
<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="C:\log\logfile_[%processid].log" />
   ...
</appender>
```

Comment: By I do not want multiple RollingFileAppenders to write to the same file. I want separate RollingFileAppenders to write to separate files.